# how to read muliple pubmed abstract text file using pubmed.mineR function readabs

Tags: r, text-mining, pubmed

I'm using R package '`pubmed.mineR`' package which provide '`gene_atomization`' for fetching genes from pubmed abstract. but '`readabs`' function read only single text file.

```
file <- list.files(pattern = "txt$")
abs <- readabs(file)
```

this code show error can anyone help for reading multiple abstract text file
I also tried '`Corpus`' function of '`tm`' package, it is still not working

Comment: Maybe `abs_list <- lapply(file, readabs)`. This gives a list of all files read by the function.

Comment: can you suggest any code which can read multiple abstract @RuiBarradas

Comment: I tried, `multiple_abs <- lapply(Sys.glob("*.txt"), readabs)` this can read muliple abstract text file, but now i stuck with `gene_atomization` function

Comment: You must give a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example that can recreate the error you are seeing. `Sys.glob("*.txt")` outputs the `*.txt` files I have on *my* disk, not on yours. Post the code that fetches the data from PubMed and everything relevant.